# Correctly format RSA signature for verification from Google Cloud

Tags: rsa, sign

I'm using Google Cloud KMS via REST API to generate a digital signature. I want to test verification.

If I follow local instructions here for CLI I get a valid verification.
[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/create-validate-signatures#kms-howto-verify-signature-rsa-cli)

However, when doing so via REST API I am stuck.

Firstly, I'm not sure how to transmit the original message. Currently I'm reading in as binary to create the digest but not sure if this is correct.

Secondly, when I receive the signature from Google using the [asymmetricSign](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.cryptoKeyVersions/asymmetricSign) method, it returns a base64 string. However, when I do it via CLI the signature is a file formatted like this:

```
940c 0a8b 907e e3ef e6b1 eb89 e911 97e6
3dd1 18be 3983 c53e 921e 0de5 22c6 4db1...
```

I've tried converting to hex and binary but whatever I do I get a 'verification failed' error.

Can someone assist please?
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my error was in how I was creating the message digest, I was using a HMAC algorithm instead of a simple Hash.